# Valid Python line with undefined variable and annotation

Tags: python, annotations

I have come accros [a post](https://pythonetc.orsinium.dev/posts/isinstance.html) with undefined variable name with some type annotation. The line is valid. What it does and what are possible usages?

```py
>>> x: int
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type hinting a variable gives static type checkers an idea of what type a variable is going to be, before it is assigned with anything:
[image]